# Reporting server configured in a separate Web server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssrs, ssrs-2016, report

I am new into configuring Reporting server and I did install and configured reporting server in a separate app server (lets say on app-01).
I have my database server running on a separate server, sql-01 server.

I have configured Reporting server and the application team deployed the reports. When I check the Web Service URL and Report Manager URL, I can see the reports in there. On clicking a report, the reports are running.

But when I run the report from the application (application code in app-01) it is not running.
Do I have to configure Reporting server for SSL? I know that SSL is for secure connection, but to access it from application from different systems do I have to configure SSL?

Any help on this area is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "i check the Web Service URL and Report Manager URL i can see the reports in there" you're using a web browser on app-01 or your desktop? When you say "from the application(application code in app-01) it is not running" are you using the ReportViewer to embed the reports, then running that app on App-01?

Comment: If you're able to access the Report Manager URL from within the machine, but not from other machines, it may be a firewall issue. If you're able to access the Report Manager URL from other machines, but not the machine running the SSRS service, it's probably a permissions issue. As written, I'm not sure I understand what the problem scenario is.

Comment: @AMtwo :I access the Web service URL and Report Manager URL from within the same app-01 machine and reports are there and it runs.But i haven't configured SSL URL.From other machine i am not able to access the URL.That is one issue i have.Also i am not able to access reports from the .Net application(it is a web application) which is installed on the user machines.I hope the question is clear now.Please let me know.